# Orthonormal basis in infinite dimensional real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Consider the vector space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. The map
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1 fg $$
defines an inner product on $C[0,1]$, with property that $\langle f,f\rangle\ge 0$ for all $f$, with equality only if $f=0$.

**Fact 1.** The set $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ of polynomial functions is linearly independent.

**Fact 2.** By applying Gram-Schmidt process, we can obtain another (ordered) countable set
$$
1=g_1, \,\, g_2, \,\, g_3, \,\, \ldots
$$
of polynomials ($g_n$ of degree $n$), which are orthonormal.

**Fact 3.** Given $f\in C[0,1]$, since
$$
\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx=0 \hskip5mm \mbox{ for all } n\ge 1 \hskip5mm \Rightarrow \hskip5mm f\equiv 0 \mbox{ (easy to check)}
$$
so this means that a  continuous function on $[0,1]$ orthogonal to $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ must be $0$ only; hence the continuous function orthogonal to $1,g_2,g_3,\ldots$ must also be $0$. Thus, the set $\{1,g_2,g_3,\ldots, \}$ is a maximal orthonormal set (and is countable).

**Fact 4.** $C[0,1]$ is of uncountable dimension over $\mathbb{R}$.

We get, from above facts that, $C[0,1]$ with above inner product, has no basis containing orthonormal vectors.

**Question:** (My question can be trivial, but I did not find any direction from references of Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra or Simmons' Topology and Modern Analysis. The question came to mind from this example, and some paragraphs in these two books. ) Is there any example of uncountable dimensional real inner product space, which possesses a basis of orthonormal vectors? Or it is always the case that an orthonormal set in any real inner product space should be finite or countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any example of uncountable dimensional real inner product space, which possesses a basis of orthonormal vectors?

Yes. Let $X$ be a vector space of uncountable dimension and let $\{x_i : i\in I\}$ be a Hamel basis for $X$. For $x,y\in X$ there exist unique representations $x = \sum_{i\in I_1}c_ix_i$ and $y = \sum_{i\in I_2}d_ix_i$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are finite subsets of $I$ and $c_i,d_i$ are scalars. Define
$$
(x,y) := \sum_{i_1\in I_1}\sum_{i_2\in I_2}c_{i_1}d_{i_2}\delta_{ij}.
$$
Then $\{x_i : i\in I\}$ is an orthonormal set in $X$ which is also a Hamel basis for $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R: \sum |f(t)|^{2}<\infty\}$ where $\sum |f(t)|^{2}$ stands for the supremum of all finite sums $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |f(t_k)|^{2}$. Define $ \langle f, g \rangle =\sum f(t)g(t)$. This a Hilbert space and the functions $\{f_t: 0 
\leq t \leq 1\}$ where $f_t(x)=1$ if $t=x$ and $0$ otherwise form an orthonormal basis for this space.

This space has  an uncountable Hamel basis (but $(f_t)$ is not one such): every vector space has  a Hamel basis and no Banach space can have a countably infinite Hamel basis. (This is a consequence of Baire Category Theorem).

In fact, there is no limit on the cardinality of an orthonormal set in an inner product space.

Comment: But, is it a *Hamel basis* (i.e., is every member in the space a **finite** linear combination of members of the set $\{f_t\}$?

Comment: It has an uncountable Hamel basis but the functions I defined do not form  a Hamel basis.  As far as I can see the example completely answers the questions you have raised. @MathsRahul

Comment: Sorry; I considered basis only for "vector space", but not for Hilbert space.

Comment: Hilbert spaces are vector spaces too.

Comment: Apologize: consider $g(x)=x$ if $x\in  \{  1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},\ldots\}$ and $0$ otherwise. So this $g$ is a member in your space; how can we write it as *Finite linear combination of members in your basis $\{f_t\}$?* (Am I doing some mistake in understanding?)

Comment: @MathsRahul Read my answer now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You haven't answered OPs question.